# Why undefined eror from javascript to another javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have A.html + A.js, B.html + B.js

and A.html

```
<div class="navbar">
  <img class="img_1" href="http://blaaaa.jpg">
  <a class="button">OK</a>
</div>
```

and A.js

```
var img_src;
  $(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('click', '.button', function() {
  var img_set = document.getElementById('img_1');
  img_src = img_set.src;
  console.log("1: "+img_src); // successfully print.
  location.href = "B.html";

});
```

and B.html

```
<div>
  <img class="img_2">
</div>
```

and B.js

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.img_2').attr("src",img_src); // not set image
   console.log("2: "+img_src); // undefined error...
 });
```

How do I know if the problem is happening?

I set two scripts on header, but it occurs error too..

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/A.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/B.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/B.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/A.js"></script>
```

Comment: Whats the error? Show us the error message.

Comment: @ko_ma I dont see `src` attribute on `img` tag in `B.html`

Comment: You have "opened" a new page which clears the javascript memory. There, you don't pass the `img_src` content. Hence it is undefined at `B.html`

Comment: `img_src` is `undefined` until you click an element with the class `button`. `$('.img_2').attr("src",img_src);` will be executed way before you click such a "button"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So instead of adding two separat JS, you can add one and play with localStorage. You can read more about localStorage here https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

```js
$(document).on('click', '.button', function() {
  if ($('#img_1').length) {
    var img_set = $('#img_1');
    localStorage.setItem('img_src', img_set.src);
    console.log("1: " + img_set.src);
    location.href = "B.html";
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('.img_2').length) {
    $('.img_2').attr("src", localStorage.getItem('img_src'));
  }
});
```

Basically, you should check if the DOM element exists or not using `length`.

Comment: That;s written in the `console.log` of B.js. You need to define `img_src` variable. It should have some value.

Comment: I was too confused with the native app. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to understand that each page have their own javascript memory. One page cannot access another page's memory content if both are on their own entity. (An exception on this is `<iframe>` but even then, it's complex to do).

Assume that you have two pages: page 1 and page 2. In page 1, you have `var value=11;` and at page 2 `var value=22;`. They have both same name but they don't have access to each other. If you use `value` in page 1, you get 11. Not 22. Similarly, in page 2, you get 22 and not 11. If you do `value = value + 100` in page 1 only, then the `value` in page 1 is 111. The `value` in page 2 is still 22. Therefore one script on a page cannot access another script which is at another page. (if you allow this, then there is a huge security risk...)

With this knowledge, let's look at your example.

At start, you have loaded `A.html` which executes the following script.

```
var img_src;
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('click', '.button', function() {
    var img_set = document.getElementById('img_1');
    img_src = img_set.src;
    console.log("1: "+img_src); // successfully print.
    location.href = "B.html";

});
```

If you click on the button, it executes the above statement in the click handler. I have added comments here below to explain what happens.

```
var img_set = document.getElementById('img_1'); // get the image by id "img_1"
img_src = img_set.src; // variable img_src is now set with the given source
console.log("1: "+img_src); // prints the source
location.href = "B.html"; // load the page to B.html
```

During the script, the variable `img_src` contains information. But at the end, you're initiating a load request, to `B.html` which is a **different** page with their own memory. When the `B.html` is loaded, this script is executed

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.img_2').attr("src",img_src); // not set image
  console.log("2: "+img_src); // undefined error...
});
```

More especially

```
$('.img_2').attr("src",img_src)
```

what you want to do here is to set the source of the image element with information that `img_src` holds. But as said before, you have reloaded the page, which creates a new memory for that page. Here, in this memory, `img_src` is not declared (and intialized).
You're trying to get information from a variable that is not known by the memory yet.

To solve it, you HAVE to have a valid variable, which is declared AND initialized. This can be done by passing over the content of `img_src` from `A.js` to `B.js` by putting it as a parameter in the URL, local storage, ...

Comment: I was too confused with the native app. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here `img_src` is not a **global** variable.You are **not define** `img_src` in B.js and try to use this that's why it giving error. 
Just declare the `img_src` in B.js
like this

```
var img_src;
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.img_2').attr("src",img_src); // not set image
   console.log("2: "+img_src); // undefined error...
 });
```

And